# How do I extend a built in type with methods?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Webpack's `require.context` to save on some duplication when importing a bunch of pages, but TypeScript complains that `Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.`.

I tried to use declaration merging to add `context` to `NodeRequired`, as described under "Merging Interfaces" in [the TS docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but I still get the same error.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
interface NodeRequire {
  context(path: string): NodeRequire;
}

const pagesCtx = require.context("./pages/"); // Throws the error
```

Comment: I recommend to place NodeRequire interface extends to own file and reference this file if needed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error; can you try to post a [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding `'webpack'` and `'webpack-env'` to the `types` array in my `tsconfig.json`

```
"types": [
  "node",
  "mocha",
  "chai",
  "webpack",
  "webpack-env"
],
```